# Approximate number of lines in 50+ GB delimited file

Tags: java

I need to validate quite large delimited file by checking if the number of rows within the file, matches(approximately) number appended to the trailer.

There are few approaches, I don't accept:

-Bringing whole file in the Heap

-Processing does not start, until validation step is complete.

What I have so far:

I tail and parse the trailer to get row count, which is very efficient.

What I was planning to do:
Get a 0,5/1mb of rows sample from a file (ideally random), count the rows in it and multiply accordingly, to get approximation of rows in the whole file.

I would not like to limit myself to creating a sample by reading first "n" number of rows, and then checking its size...

Question:

Is it possible to get a sample like that, without reading whole file? Can I start fetching n number of rows starting from the middle of the file, without recreating part of the original file (eg `head '-c/n' 'x' file.csv > file1.csv` is not efficient)?

Comment: Why you have a 50 GB CSV file? **That** is inefficient.

Comment: You might be able to use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` - seek to the middle of the file, read until the next delimiter. Now read, counting delimiters until the next delimiter after the approximate length of the sample, and divide the number of delimiters you encountered (not counting the one you found immediately after seeking?) by the length you read. You'll read slightly more bytes than the sample length as the seek doesn't position you at the start of an entry, and you need to read until the end of the last entry to find how many bytes it is.

Comment: I assuming GNU/Linux.. Is 'wc -l <filename>' too slow for you?

Comment: wc -l reads whole file
@nellar thank you, I had no idea about existence of that Class, just had a look at it and this will suffice

Comment: Also check out [`LineNumberReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) which automatically counts lines as you read from a reader, which also includes skipping content (lines are also counted in skipped bytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a sample like that, without reading whole file?

Yes.

> Can I start fetching n number of rows starting from the middle of the file, without recreating part of the original file  ..

Yes.

- Use `File.length()` to get the length of the file.
- Open the files using `FileInputStream`
- Use `FileInputStream.skip(N)` to skip to the offset you want to sample.  (I've checked the Java 8 source, and `skip` is efficient.  It uses an `lseek` syscall rather than reading bytes ...)
- Finally, wrap the stream in a `BufferedReader(InputStreamReader)` and use `BufferedReader.readLine()` to count M lines and measure their average length.

---

Stepping back a bit, I have a couple of points on the problem itself:

> I need to validate quite large delimited file by checking if the number of rows within the file, matches(approximately) number appended to the trailer.

1. It is not clear that an approximate match is much help.  I guess, it depends on what failure modes you are trying to detect.
2. Wouldn't you expect the average record to be the same across most / all input files?  If so, it may make more sense to validate the row count (from the trailer) against the file size x the expected average record count.
3. Sampling won't pick up problems where a small percentage of records are bad.  And that badness could be empty lines or records with many / most / all fields empty.

There is also the question of whether it is a good idea to do a separate "quick" validation of a file this big.  If you detect a problem, what can you do?  Re-fetch it?  Re-send it?  Wouldn't it be better to do a full validation ... while you are processing it?  Wouldn't it be better to make the files smaller?  For files this size, wouldn't it be better to pick a more compact representation than CSV's?

Comment: He is showing you 4+ year old source code.  I can confirm that that this is true in Java 8,

Answer (score 0):

Bringing the whole file into the Heap is indeed probably not a good idea if your file is 50 GB in size.

You could use a memory mapped file, which allows you for example to read through the whole file without actually loading it completely in one piece into main memory.

You might use RandomAccessFile and MappedByteBuffer to open
a Region of your File as a MemoryMapped Buffer.
Have a look at the RandomAccessFile.getChannel and FileChannel.map methods.